# JS toLocaleString shows numeric value for short month instead of month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get short month name for Lithuanian locale from date

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('lt-LT', {month: 'short'}) // '06'
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('lt-LT', { month: 'short' }).format(new Date()) // '06'
```

However it gives me numeric value. I also tried moment library and it gave me correct result

```
moment(new Date()).locale('lt-LT').format('MMM') // 'bir'
```

Am I doing something wrong using toLocaleDateString or moment library uses some other sources for dates?

Comment: From MDN -> `The locales and options parameters may not be supported in all implementations, because support for the internalization API is optional,`   But what is strange in this case is that the `long` version seems OK.  You would think if the people doing the locale for `lt-LT` were bothered to put in the `long` names, doing the `short` ones would be easier.. :)   Even stranger is that it's the same on both Chrome & Firefox..

Comment: [There was a similar bug filed with Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1742055) for Estonia where the short name was being mapped back to the full name. They recommended filing an issue with the [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/CLDR/issues/?filter=allissues).

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting numeric values instead of short month names when using the `toLocaleDateString` or `Intl.DateTimeFormat` methods in JavaScript, it is likely because the specified locale (`lt-LT` in this case) does not support short month names. Some locales may only provide numeric representations of months.

To confirm whether the `lt-LT` locale supports short month names, you can use the following code:

```
const options = { month: 'short' };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('lt-LT', options).formatToParts(new Date()));
```